# Redirect to a new URL using C#/JavaScript and logout

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

I have an Action Result, that I want to use to pass a new URL to redirect to via JS and LOGOUT from the site. What is the best way to approach this?

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() });
            }
            else
            {
                    return Json(new { newUrl = "http://www.google.com" });     
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new UpdateResponse() { Success = true });
                }
            }
```

UPDATE REDIRECT LINK HERE

```
vmCartChangeAccount.ApplyResponse = function () {
            if (!app.ajaxService.inCriticalSection()) {
                app.ajaxService.criticalSection(true);
                app.ajaxService.ajaxPostJson("@Url.Action("ChangeAccountOrLocation", "Cart")",
                        ko.mapping.toJSON(vmCartChangeAccount.Form),
                        function (result) {
                            // redirect to NEW URL
                            app.ajaxService.criticalSection(false);
                            window.location.replace(**REPLACETORUL HERE**);
                        }, function (result) {
                            vmCartChangeAccount.Form.ClearCart(false);
                            app.doneLoading();
                            app.ajaxService.criticalSection(false);
                            $("#error-modal").modal();
                        }, vmCartChangeAccount.ModalErrors);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

**By doing this you can redirect to the HomeController which you configure in the startup.cs file**

```
  <li class="nav-item">
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Test" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {area = ""})">
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
            </form>
        </li>
```